# Shell command error with XAMPP on Yosemite - dyld: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_intarray_bind

Tags: php, shell, ffmpeg, xampp

I'm trying to run a simple shell command with PHP. I'm using XAMPP on OS X Yosemite, this is my script

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec(PHP_BINDIR.'/ffmpeg 2>&1');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

I've placed my ffmpeg executable in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin` but when I run it, I got this error on the page instead of the shell output:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_intarray_bind
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
  Expected in: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
```

What this error means? Why is involved Sqlite3?